# SVG fill area under the path only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a trend graph which looks like this:

[image]

```
<svg width="175" height="50" viewBox="0 0 175 50" fill="true" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="black"><defs><linearGradient id="react-trend-vertical-gradient-9449655103672434" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop></linearGradient></defs><clipPath id="cut-off-bottom"><rect x="0" y="-8" width="175" height="50"></rect></clipPath><path id="react-trend-9449655103672434" d="M 8,42
L 16.47383891803467,26.77906669817169
S 19.357142857142858,21.6 25.035714285714285,23.3
L 25.035714285714285,23.3
S 30.714285714285715,25 34.51372707642143,20.450228708486538
L 36.39285714285714,18.2
S 42.07142857142857,11.399999999999999 47.75,18.199999999999996
L 47.75,18.2
S 53.42857142857143,25 58.349935306257734,17.63343017050729
L 59.23065242856076,16.31512403775182
S 64.78571428571428,8 69.09240847758271,17.025097514028683
L 73.2924185202937,25.826627993470822
S 76.14285714285714,31.8 81.82142857142857,28.4
L 81.82142857142857,28.4
S 87.5,25 92.42420103267804,20.577510015934436
L 93.17857142857143,19.9
S 98.85714285714286,14.8 103.0970844759733,21.146579278500923
L 106.53759956873661,26.296532687794436
S 110.21428571428571,31.8 115.89285714285714,35.2
L 115.89285714285714,35.2
S 121.57142857142857,38.6 124.42186719399201,32.62662799347083
L 128.621877236703,23.82509751402868
S 132.92857142857144,14.8 137.792791259808,23.537240149692863
L 139.4214944544777,26.46275985030714
S 144.28571428571428,35.2 148.5924084775827,26.174902485971316
L 151.3361629509887,20.425097514028685
S 155.64285714285714,11.399999999999999 159.1224146222211,20.775109585908968
L 167,42" fill="#316BBE" fill-opacity="0.1" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" stroke="url(#react-trend-vertical-gradient-9449655103672434)"></path></svg>
```

It renders fine when the first and last values are '0', but if I use '11' as the last value for example, it renders like this:

[image]

```
<svg width="175" height="50" viewBox="0 0 175 50" fill="true" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="black"><defs><linearGradient id="react-trend-vertical-gradient-214921560992256" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#316BBE"></stop></linearGradient></defs><clipPath id="cut-off-bottom"><rect x="0" y="-8" width="175" height="50"></rect></clipPath><path id="react-trend-214921560992256" d="M 8,42
L 16.28365848373006,28.473339834457946
S 19.357142857142858,23.454545454545453 25.035714285714285,25
L 25.035714285714285,25
S 30.714285714285715,26.545454545454547 34.69553752776538,22.211375956051867
L 36.39285714285714,20.363636363636367
S 42.07142857142857,14.181818181818183 47.75,20.363636363636363
L 47.75,20.363636363636367
S 53.42857142857143,26.545454545454547 58.399315977540795,19.781376771556836
L 59.107142857142854,18.81818181818182
S 64.78571428571428,11.09090909090909 69.24260104627207,19.581673348301074
L 73.13797820060304,27.002712043687463
S 76.14285714285714,32.72727272727273 81.82142857142857,29.636363636363637
L 81.82142857142857,29.636363636363637
S 87.5,26.545454545454547 92.50806084171919,22.456540376229277
L 93.17857142857143,21.90909090909091
S 98.85714285714286,17.272727272727273 103.1982846379807,23.180055710917145
L 106.38573439034217,27.51746589423348
S 110.21428571428571,32.72727272727273 115.89285714285714,35.81818181818181
L 115.89285714285714,35.81818181818181
S 121.57142857142857,38.90909090909091 124.57630751368266,33.18453022550565
L 128.28085740391924,26.127034379726176
S 132.92857142857144,17.272727272727273 138.1510407929314,25.800670385713047
L 139.0632449213543,27.290238705196046
S 144.28571428571428,35.81818181818182 148.93342831036648,26.963874711182914
L 152.63797820060304,19.906378865403447
S 155.64285714285714,14.181818181818183 161.32142857142856,11.090909090909092
L 167,8" fill="#316BBE" fill-opacity="0.1" clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)" stroke="url(#react-trend-vertical-gradient-214921560992256)"></path></svg>
```

How can I get it to only fill the area under the trend line? The svg is generated with [react-trend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-trend).

Comment: You example code saves my week! Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a duplicate of the path, set `stroke` to `none` on the first path and `fill` to `none` on the second, and add `L 167,42 L 8,42 Z` to the `d` attribute of the first path.

[Example](https://codepen.io/jackmaurer/pen/wvBpmWK)

Comment: That actually works great, but I need to make it dynamic. How did you come up with those numbers?

Comment: 167 is the maximum x-coordinate in the path (the x-coordinate of the last point), 42 the max y-coordinate (the y-coordinate of the first point), and 8 the minimum x-coordinate (the x-coordinate of the first point).